# Can I use BLAST to compare 2 non-biological strings?

Tags: blast

I know what BLAST (The Basic Local Alignment Search Tool) was designed for. But I am interested in using such advanced text comparison and its final effects.

Comment: You want to use the Berkeley Lazy Abstraction Software Verification Tool to compare non-biological strings ?!

Answer (score 2):

You could use vmatch.

If you want to use a tool for local alignment of subtrings, you might want to use STELLAR though, paper: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/S9/S15/

It does everything blast does, but has quite convenient option to use chars.